# Parse json from curl using shell

Tags: bash, shell, curl

When I curl to my URL, I get a JSON in the following format:

```
{"busyexecutors":0,
 "computers":[{"displayName":"Master","actions":[{},{},{}]},
              {"displayName":"137.0.01","actions":[{},{},{}]}]}
```

I want to extract only displayName where it's not equal to Master. So the output should be "137.0.0.1".

Let me know whether I can achieve this without external utilities like jq.

Comment: "I don't want to use extra utilities" - why? Portability? And how broad is your "like" - is Ruby okay (as it's installed on most current Unix-likes)? Because doing this in pure shell is somewhat fragile.

Comment: I agree with Amadan. Either you are using jq, or you are using something like python and ruby. Pure shell is simply not capable of handling this.

Comment: Thanks Amadan & skyline..wanted to know whether its possible with just shell. i don't understand ..what do you mean by fragile.

Comment: Shell utilities are typically line-oriented, whereas structured file formats very often exhibit variability in whitespace, including line breaks; so creating a parser for a structured file format using line-oriented tools tends to produce code which has a number of corner cases where results are invalid and incorrect, or the program simply aborts.  This is a FAQ; see e.g. http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ (the topic is HTML and regex but it extends readily to JSON and `cut | head | tac | rev`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few good reasons *not* to use a proper JSON parser when working with JSON.

```
jq -r '.computers | .[].displayName | select(.!="Master")' <<EOF
{"busyexecutors":0,
 "computers":[{"displayName":"Master","actions":[{},{},{}]},
          {"displayName":"137.0.01","actions":[{},{},{}]}]}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, this is a bad idea. However, if you insist to do it:

```php
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  split($0, z, /"/)
  for (y in z)
    if (z[y] == "displayName")
      if (z[y+2] != "Master")
        print z[y+2]
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `awk` is also a utility... :P